# How does gnu screen re-index the window id after the kill window, ensuring that the window id is always incremented continuously?

Tags: gnu-screen

After gnu screen kills a window, the id of the following window is discontinuous.

Chrome's tabs use Ctrl + 1 through Ctrl + 8 to switch, digit is the current actual order of the tabs, not affected by the previously closed tabs, I hope gnu screen can also do this